# Webforms: pages 1,2 of 4 not being displayed

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm developing my first Drupal 8 Webforms application. It had three pages to start with and I had managed to get it to do what I wanted it to. I have also developed a WebformHandler to go with it.

I needed to add an extra page between the old 1st and 2nd page. I created this using the "build" tab and it was created in 4th position in the list of pages, so I dragged it up to 2nd position and did "Save Elements".

But then, when I used the "View" tab to try out the form, the dialogue started at the 3rd page (the old 2nd page). I have now deleted the new 2nd page and appear to have the same old configuration that worked, but using the "View" tab still ignores the first page.

I have flushed all the caches; I have looked in the database for anything obvious (but not found anything); I have looked at the YAML files in the module I created for the Webform; I have even rebooted the server.

I have tried to scan the entire Drupal file tree looking for files that have been modified in the last couple of hours (since the webform last started correctly), but I haven't managed to find anything, except the WebformHandler, but that isn't called before the initial page is shown.

Using a different browser (Safari instead of Chrome) produces the same result, so I guess the problem is on the server and not the client.

Somewhere, something is holding information about my webform: could anyone help me to locate it?

Comment: most likely a indentation in the source yml enable webform devel and view the source see if any thing is miss aligned ?

Comment: If you can't figure this out, please export the webform config and create a GIST (https://gist.github.com/) so that we can look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have found the problem. The element editor in Webforms includes an "Access" tab. For the pages in question, I had removed all permissions for all roles under this tab, which included the "administer" role I work under, so – obviously :-) – I had no access to those pages.

Comment: @StephenWinnall Could you post this as an answer for the benefit of future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong places...

The element editor in Webforms includes an `Access` tab. For the pages that were not being shown I had removed all the permissions, which included the permissions of ‘Administrator’, the user I was logged in as. So – obviously – those pages were not shown.

Duuhh.